# SwitchCompat won't be unchecked after a fixed time of the day

Tags: java, android, date, time, switchcompat

I am using switchCompat in my android application. I want something like that after 10:40 am, the switch won't be unchecked, if it is checked once before the time. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand, why none is coming to help me!

Comment: Your question seems poorly researched and may for that reason not attract many answers. What did your search turn up? In what way was it insufficuent? What have you tried? (Sorry, I don’t know SwitchCompat myself, and only little Android.)